# How to update datatables data from the server-side

Tags: php, datatables

Is there a way to process the data that's coming from the server side in datatables? What I mean by process is that when the field is a URL I want to be able to wrap it in anchor tags. Or if the field is of boolean type I want to render a checkbox instead. Here's what my code currently looks like:

```
$('#products').dataTable( {
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "search-results.php"
});
```

`search-results.php` returns the data from the database. I can pretty much wrap the data from the server-side but I'm thinking about the extra html that I need to fetch every time the user performs a search so if possible I'd like to do it in the client side. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use aoColumnDefs with mRender.

```
"aoColumnDefs": [
    {
    "aTargets": ["url_addr"],
        "mRender": function (url) {
            return "<a href='" + url + "'>" + url + "</a>";
        }
    },
],
```

For aTargets, you can use either class name or index number of that column

```
"aTargets": ["url_addr"], //class name of the column, or
"aTargets": [0], //if URL is in column 1
```